# Is there a word that means made of the same constituents but in opposite proportion?

Tags: single-word-requests

Example:

Progressive music with funk elements:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Tdu4uKSZ3M

Funk music with progressive elements:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pzxwZ6wjDAM

Comment: According to the full OED, [*One proposition is the **converse** of another, when the datum and conclusion of the one are respectively taken as the conclusion and datum of the other.*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/40762?rskey=oEKX0y&result=3#eid) By the same token, one could equate OP's  *prog +funk* with *datum+conclusion* - in both cases, the "roles" of the two constituent parts are reversed in the "converse" form.

Comment: Coming from a similar direction as @FumbleFingers, "complement" might be useful here.

Answer (score 1):

'this is same music with funk and progressive elements in inverse proportions'
'the ratio of the different elements are inversed.'

In the case of liquids we can use comparisons using 'diluted' and 'concentrated' to indicate how much of which substance is in the glass relative to the other.

I'll edit this post if I think of any other...

Comment: Could you be more explicit

Comment: what may be helpful for you may not be for another, and the same vica versa. That's what the up/down voting system is for, right?

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/help/stackexchange also where do I see 'site standards'?

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer    Please note the part about including links and context.

Comment: Aren't you doing the same thing? :|

Comment: I welcome criticism with open arms but please be constructive~ if you want, you can help me improve my answer ^^